# How one aquires UEFI utilities?

Tags: windows-7, uefi

I seem unable to locate any UEFI (EFI) utilities on the web.
I am particularly interested in nvrboot.efi as I need to delete duplicate boot manager entry in nvr. Some people mention windows msutil folder, but I do not see one on my system.
(windows 7 ultimate). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the program, you could try a Web search on it.

Beyond that, check the [Tianocore project site on Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tianocore/) and assorted links from it. A number of EFI utilities are available as part of that project, although a lot of that project is rather arcane.

As user50172 suggests, you can use the `bcfg` command in an EFI shell to manage EFI boot loader entries. [This rEFInd page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#efishell) describes using `bcfg` to add entries to the NVRAM. The Arch Linux [wiki description of `bcfg`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#bcfg) also has information on it, including deleting entries. Both pages include download links for EFI shell binaries. The rEFInd project includes download links for USB flash drive and CD-R versions of rEFInd, both of which include an EFI shell.

Most EFI-enabled OSes also include tools to manipulate EFI boot manager entries. In Windows, `bcdedit` can do the job, although I'm not sure how to delete entries, offhand. In Linux, the `efibootmgr` utility is what you want. Type `man efibootmgr` to learn how to use it, and pay attention to the `-b` and `-B` options.

Answer (score 0):

Use bcfg from UEFI Shell.

You'll find the syntax with 'help bcfg'

Answer (score 0):

Independent of Win7 or any other OS . . .

A pre-compiled, non-Secure Boot (not signed by Microsoft, so you will have to disable Secure Boot in your UEFI Setup), UEFI Shell.efi is available at: 
https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/UDK2018/ShellBinPkg/UefiShell/X64
You may change the Branch from UDK2018 to another if you prefer.

Place it on a USB flash drive in the root directory \Shell.efi and a copy to \EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi to cover two most common cases.  You might have to manually select the USB flash drive to boot it.

Once you reboot into the UEFI Shell on the USB flash drive, you can use the 'bcfg' built-in shell command.

'bcfg boot dump' to list the existing boot entries.
'bcfg boot rm #' to remove/delete boot entry # from the 'bcfg boot dump' list output.

Note: Some UEFI firmware will automatically re-populate the boot list after you 'bcfg boot rm #' them.

Comment: The author was looking for utilities to modify their EFI configuration.  The author wasn't looking for EFI firmware itself.  Besides Tianocore was already suggested.